# Quebrar linha em determinado caracter

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma aplicação em que um `TLabel` recebe um linha de um `TMemo`,

porem o `form` que estou exibindo tem que ser pequena, e a informação é grande.

Minha ideia é que quando chegar em um determinado numero de caracteres a frase continuaria na linha de baixo.

Sendo assim estou usando a função abaixo para contar o numero de caracteres na primeira linha do `TMemo`

```
tamMemoCaption:=inttostr(Length(form1.memo5.Lines.text));
```

O que necessito, é que quando o tamanho chegar a 24 por exemplo do texto do `TMemo`, a partir dai ele quebrar para a linha de baixo ou um novo `TLabel` receber as informações

Tentei usar a opção `WordWrap`, mas sem resultados.

Alguma orientação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine e tente usar a mesma função interna que já esta usando a `Length`.

```
procedure CopiaApenasPartesString;
var
  vRestante,
  vTextoAuxiliar : String;  
begin
  vTextoAuxiliar := O texto que você esta inserindo no TMemo;

  if (Length(vTextoAuxiliar) > 24) then
  begin
    Memo.Lines.Add(Copy(vTextoAuxiliar,1,24); //Copia os Primeiros 24 Caracteres
    vRestante := Copy(vTextoAuxiliar,1,Length(vTextoAuxiliar));
    if (Length(vRestante) > 24) then
      Memo.Lines.Add(Copy(vRestante,1,24); //Copia mais 24 Caracteres
  end;
end;
```

Dessa forma, a cada 24 caracteres o texto é inserido no `TMemo`.

Observe que eu não usei nenhuma estrutura de repetição, você pode montar Array conforme a necessidade ou tamanho do Texto!

Porém, usando o próprio `TMemo`, definindo um `Width` para ele que caiba 24 caracteres e com a propriedade `WordWrap` ativada já deve funcionar sem código auxiliar algum!

Comment: com pequenos ajustes ficou como eu precisava !